# EmguCV Bitmap constructor is very slow on first process

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I am trying to detect a document from camera and crop it using OpenCV. While I am doing this on my local there is no problem, but when it work on test the row below takes more then 2 minutes. I tried to build my project in release mode but nothing changed. I am using EMGU.CV 4.1.1.3497. The thing what confuses me: it is in eventhandler and it works more then 1 time in a second. It is slow for only first load. Then it works fast.

```
private void Device_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone())
    {
        using (Image<Bgr, byte> imageCV = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap)) --this row takes 2 minutes on first load
        {
          //finding contour etc.
        }
    }
}
```

ProcMon Logs:
[image]

Tried to build on release mod.
Tried to add test all of my dll versions on local.
Tried it on different devices and cameras.

Comment: My guess would be some kind of timeout when the library is loaded or compiled. I would suggest some profiler to see where the time is spent. [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) may also be useful to check the system calls and if there is odd failures.

Comment: Hi Jonah, thank you for your response. I don't see a spesific failure but as i control with procman i can see reading file opencv_videoio_ffmpeg411.dll took more then 1 minute. Do you have any suggestion to avoid from this? I added some logs above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the trace it looks like it is reading from `\\path\...`, I would assume this is a network drive. I would highly recommend that all the program files are run from a local drive instead. I.e. just copy the program to a local folder.

Network drives can have far higher latency than local drives. And if there is many small reads this can add up.

This sounds like it matches your experience, when you run it locally everything works fine. Once it has actually loaded all of the files it also runs fine.

Comment: As you said when I copied files to local and try i didn't have this problem. We will try to cache those files for clients. Thank you Jonas!